# General error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'file_material' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to assign the user_id with the current user but it give me this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'file_material' doesn't have a default value
```

[Images error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Wic.png)

with these Model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id_sub_detail';
    protected $table = 'subject_details';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_sub_detail',
        'id_subject',
        'start_date',
        'time',
        'title',
        'sub_topics',
        'room',
        'file_material',
    ];
```

However this method do the job

```
public function UploadSubjectDetail(Request $request){
        $addSubjectDetail= new SubjectDetail();

        $addSubjectDetail->id_subject = $request->input('id_subject');
        $addSubjectDetail->start_date = $request->input('start_date');
        $addSubjectDetail->time = $request->input('time');
        $addSubjectDetail->title = $request->input('title');
        $addSubjectDetail->sub_topics = $request->input('sub_topics');
        $addSubjectDetail->room = $request->input('room');

        if ($request->file('file_material')) {
            $file = $request->file('file_material');
            $filename = date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path('upload/material/'), $filename);
            $addSubjectDetail['file_material'] = $filename;
        }

        $addSubjectDetail->save();
        return redirect()->back();
```

any idea why this fail?
[Images XAMPP Mysqli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbudW.png)

Comment: According to your db table schema, file_material cannot be null but you have not assigned a value in the insert query (and this field has NO default value too)

Comment: There are two issues with the code, firstly, if $request does not have file input, `file_material` column will not be given any value. Like @KenLee mentioned, since that column is not nullable, it has to have a value.

The second issue, although not directly related to your question is that variable `$addSubjectDetail` is an instance of `SubjectDetail`, thus, it is an object, but you are trying to set `file_material` on it as if it is an associative array `$addSubjectDetail['file_material']`.

Comment: I saw your mysql image . 
Add your migation structure here too.